# SQL - How to not display certain items if they met the criteria

Tags: sql

[image: Picture of the database table]

So I am trying to get all the Items that do not have the word 'sweet' in the description
However because there are some are duplicate items with different descriptions, That item still shows up in the list. For example, Seafood should not show up because one of its descriptions had 'sweet' in them.

[image: Picture of after I ran the query]

How do I construct a query so that all the items (including the duplicate ones) do not show up in the list if they had the word 'Sweet' in one of their descriptions?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select categoryname
from categories
group by categoryname
having sum(case when description like '%sweet%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select * from categories c
where categoryName not in (select categoryName from categories c2 where description like '%sweet%')
```